# Can you make an HTTPS request to an HTTP server?

Tags: node.js, http, https, server, backend

I'm using Node as the server technology here. If I make an HTTPS request to an HTTP server - will the request still go through? Is this a bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the client will initiate a TLS handshake that the server cannot accept. HTTPS is a two-way street.

Comment: Also, they listen on different ports per default. So no connection would be established.